# The name 'AvaloniaXamlLoaderPortableXaml' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, xaml, avaloniaui

I just upgraded to the latest version of Avalonia.Desktop (0.7.0) and now I'm getting this compile error. It appears this method is now missing from Application. What are we supposed to call now to initialize the page?

Comment: Reinstall the nuget. also they may have refactored that class into another nuget, so check around

Comment: Any documentation around?

Comment: I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling. The method is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use`AvaloniaXamlLoader`. `AvaloniaXamlLoaderPortableXaml` was a transitional name that was kept from the times when we were switching from OmniXAML to PortableXaml.